# .NET:How to implement "Hashes"

Tags: vb.net, hash

In some programming languages, hashes are a simple concept:

You give a "keyword" and the hash will return a "value". This is very helpful for linking two values etc...

I want to do something similar for my application:

Basically depending on what items from a checkList are checked, another list is populated by text lines.

So, is it possible to create some kind of table where if I send a keyword it will return to me with a text line?

A good example is a shopping catalog. You check an item, and a list has to show the item's description, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx).

There are some examples of how to use it in the documentation on MDSN. There are also some more examples on [dotnetperls](http://dotnetperls.com/dictionary-vbnet).

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for =D